# Android studio - run annotation processor manually

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, annotation-processing

Is that possible? I have changed a few basic things in my code and want to make a clean build to see how many things needs to be adjusted now. This results in 1000s of `cannot find symbol class ...` messages in my Messages Gradle Build window.

So I want to run the annotation processor manually now to get rid of those messages and only see the relevant messages (looking through so many messages is cumbersome and I know that all annotated classes can be build by the annotation processor without problems).

Is that somehow possible? How do I run the annotation processor in android studio manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to run Annotation processors manually (unless of course you are developing one).

Make sure you have Annotation Processors enabled in Android Studio (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-annotation-processing.html), `Build > Clean` project, and then `Build > Rebuild` project.

If you have everything set up correctly, this should work. However if your build is failing due to an annotation processor (Example: Dagger not meeting dependencies graph) then you will need to figure out the underlying issue.

Comment: it fails because of compilation errors.... When making a build android studio will never run the annotation processor if there is a compile error somewhere in my code. That's why I want to run the processor without compiling... I simply WANT to run the processor only

Comment: That's incorrect. All annotation processors are executed before compilation of any other code. Therefore, if you have a compilation error in a class referenced by the annotation processor, you need to fix that, and you wont solve it by manually running the annotation processor. As a matter of fact, it should return the same errors than if it was run by the build.

Comment: I'm using annotation processors for my database, moving all this code to a module and compiling this module works. After doing so I see about 100 errors in my main app. If I would have been able to run the annotation processor manually, I would have been able to see those 100 errors without all the missing class errors and without moving my database code to a module just for the sake of compiling the module and so force the annotation processor to run on those classes...

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to run an annotation processor manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `kotlin` and using `kapt` there should be a task named `kaptDebugKotlin` you can access using gradle CLI by simply executing this command in the terminal `./gradlew app:kaptDebugKotlin` 
Make sure you replace app with your module name in case you have a multi-module project.

If you are working with `java` then simply replace `app:kaptDebugKotlin` with `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` and that should execute your annotation processor.

to force the build to continue in case of compilation error add `--continue` to the command in the terminal.

Happy coding.